# avoiding two queries in two tables

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have two tables.
In the first one you can find something like this:

```
id    date
```

In the second one :

```
id    product
```

In my app I've done a list that shows all the dates in the first table. When the user picks one I want to do the following : get from the first table the id of the date the user picked in the list and return the products from the second table that have that id.

Now, I can easily do this with 2 queries but I figured it would be better, for the app, the user and for my knowledge to learn about a better way of doing this.

Clearly, I'm a beginner in mysql, I searched for a way to do this and found some stuff I didn't knew about but that don't apply to what I need.

So how can I do this ? what do I need to use ?

Thanks and have a nice day !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT p.product 
FROM table1 d, table2 p
WHERE d.date = 'selecteddate' AND d.id = p.id
```

Comment: Yes,worked like a charm ! Thanks a lot,i'll look into those kind of stuff to get to understand them better though it is very easy.

Comment: happy to help! things looks easy when we know the exact solution :D

Comment: Some comments on the solution  1. Prefer ANSI style join as it give better structure in the SQL  2. Avoid passing date as String which is causing a lot of problem

Answer (score 2):

In fact this is a simple SQL question.  Just join the two tables and everything will work

```
select t1.product -- and other fields you want
from T1 t1
inner join T2
  on t1.id = t2.id
where t1.date = :inputDate
```

Strongly suggest you to give some further study in SQL